# Generating line offset, perpendicular using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, perpendicular, offset

I'm trying to generate two line offsets from a line but I'm having problems generating them as they should be.

Using PostGIS

`select st_asgeojson(st_union(the_geom)) from (
select ST_Line_Substring(ST_OffsetCurve(line_geom,0.00005),0,1) as the_geom from table_name where id = 7382
  UNION
  select ST_Line_Substring(ST_OffsetCurve(line_geom,-0.00005),0,1) as the_geom from table_name where id = 7382
UNION
  select (line_geom) as the_geom from table_name where id = 7382) as a`

the problem I'm seeing right now is the angle between the start/end of given line isn't perpendicular to the start/end of the other lines

Result:
[image: current result]
Expected:
[image: expected result]

EDIT: lines' geometry and srid

`"LINESTRING(-8.69371814905576 40.5676685897826,-8.69334901004008 40.567864446704)",4326
"LINESTRING(-8.6936947144568 40.5676244216994,-8.69332557544112 40.5678202786208)",4326
"LINESTRING(-8.69330214084216 40.5677761105376,-8.69367127985784 40.5675802536163)",4326`

Comment: This could be a reprojection issue. I see your offset is *very* small so it it probably in degrees and that is not very suitable for this kind of operations. Can you add an ST_Text(line_geom) and ST_Srid(line_geom) output of your geometry to the question?

Comment: I found another way to accomplish what I wanted, the result is the same but I know for fact that it's now for sure a projection problem.

Answer (score 1):

It was certainly a projection issue. You should first make sure you project your data into a local system. Here is what I used (for an offset of 2 meter in the portugese projection 3763):

```
WITH line AS (
SELECT 
ST_Transform(
    ST_SetSrid(
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(-8.6936947144568 40.5676244216994,-8.69332557544112 40.5678202786208)')
    ,4326) 
,3763)
geom
)
SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(geom,2) geom FROM line
UNION ALL
SELECT ST_OffsetCurve(geom,-2) geom FROM line
UNION ALL
SELECT geom FROM line;
```

I removed your LineSubstring since it didn't do anything.